# How do I match multiple words in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb, text, backend

I have a field in my collection call paragraph.
Now I am doing a regex search like this -

```
db.getCollection('test').find({ paragraph: {$regex: "/test|word/i"} })
```

This will search for test or word in the paragraph. Is there any way where I can search for both the words(test and word) in the field.

I've a workaround but it is not quite useful. `{$regex: "/test.*word/i"}` - It is saying that do the search for "test" and if test is found match with "word" and then return the result.
Also I want to ignore stemmed word if its possible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's build upon your `{$regex: "/test.*word/i"}` example. Based on docs at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/, the proper formats are:

```
{ $regex: /test.*word/i }
{ $regex: "test.*word", $options: "i" }
```

To exclude stemmed words, use word boundaries:

```
{ $regex: /\btest\b.*\bword\b/i }
{ $regex: "\\btest\\b.*\\bword\\b", $options: "i" }
```

Note that a backslash needs to be escaped in a string.

For an AND logic of two words in either order do this:

```
{ $regex: /\btest\b.*\bword\b|\bword\b.*\btest\b/i }
```

As you can imagine that gets unwieldy for more than two words.

For an AND logic of multiple words in any order you can use a positive lookahead, that tests each word:

```
{ $regex: /^(?=.*\btest\b)(?=.*\bword\b)(?=.*\bAnotherOne\b)/i }
```

Details on AND regex logic at https://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Codev/TWikiPresentation2018x10x14Regex?slideshow=on;skin=print;extralog=-+caching+topic#GoSlide25

Comment: Actually I'm doing that. But that works for only two words,

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion for if there are more than two words.

Comment: But this regex `{ $regex: /^(?=.*\btest\b)(?=.*\bword\b)(?=.*\bAnotherOne\b)/i }` is not [working](https://regexr.com/).

Comment: Can you please help me more on this. Just write this para - `hello world. Javascript is the best and I'm learning regex, this is a test word and this includes another word.  test word another  test word. hello this is test word anotherone. `. Its not matching the suggestions.

Comment: Ah, MongoDB `$regex` might test for matched text length instead of null for no match. Try this: `{ $regex: /^(?=.*\btest\b)(?=.*\bword\b)(?=.*\bAnotherOne\b).*/i }`. The `.*` at the end matches everything, e.g. the matched text (if all lookahead are ok) is the whole string.